# Is there a way to configure webpack-dev-server to open a specified browser window ? For example Chrome Canary on mac

Tags: google-chrome, webpack-dev-server

I have googled about it, could not find anything related to the question.

The reason I want this is for workflow issues. I have setup a developer account on chrome canary and would like to keep all things related to development to that browser.

**In devServer options object, is there a place where I can tell webpack-dev-server to open "Google Chrome Canary". I use Mac, if that makes a difference.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like they added a possibility to set a browser name in `open` option in v2.8.0.
Note that at least for some browsers browser name will be OS-specific (it seems to be passed directly to `opn` package, therefore, same rules):

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/825

In addition to googling, you may want to search in package's repository Issues as well. Takes some time and "popularity" before google shows it on top of other matches.

Comment: Running the script with `... --open "Google Chrome Canary" ` solved it for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I fixed the issue.
In package.json:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open chrome",
```

of course, you can use webpack.config.js instead webpack.dev.js

In webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
        ...
        open: 'chrome'
      },
```

This is for Google Chrome, so just use any other browser name.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS:

1. Don't use the devServer property in webpack.config.js
2. Use this in package.json: `"start": "webpack-dev-server --open 'google chrome'"`

Comment: You can use the devServer property in webpack@4: `open: 'Google Chrome',` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen

Answer (score 2):

I had to specify this to force `webpack-dev-server` to open the window in the Chrome app on my **Mac**:

```
open: {
  app: {
    name: 'Google Chrome'
  }
}
```

So in your case same solution with `Google Chrome Canary` might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the [browserSyncPlugin](https://github.com/Va1/browser-sync-webpack-plugin) has a "--browser" [option](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line) to which you can pass e.g. "chrome".

Please note that I didn't find what exactly you have to specify as the value, but "chrome" seems to work on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use BrowserSync with webpack-dev-server. But this is not what I meant to ask, so I am asking without using browsersync, is it possible to create a rule, webpack-dev-server opens 'Google Chrome Canary' browser ?

Answer (score 0):

For Linux: (KDE Neon / Ubuntu)

- Don't use the devServer property in webpack.config.js
- Use this in package.json: `"start": "yarn serve --open chromium-browser"`

I tried all kind of variants for webpack.config.js like
/usr/bin/chromium-browser, Chromium, Chromium-Webbrowser, Chrome, chromium, chromium-webbrowser and what not - nothing worked